# Object with same memory reference LiveData with Room DB and DiffUtil

Tags: kotlin, android-room, shared-memory, android-livedata, android-diffutils

I am trying to integrate the list with Room DB and Diff Utils,

[image: Flow Diagram]

Issue Facing:

- When an item(s) is updated, LiveData got triggered but existing items in the adapter are the same as newItems.
  eg. OldList = [0 : "zero", 1: "one"] NewList = [0: "0", 1:"1"] when update triggered Adapter.currentList = [0:"0", 1:"1"] issue happening without setting items to adapter list
- Old List same as NewList without set

Code:

**Room - Listening Changes :**

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_topic_list ORDER BY created_at DESC")
abstract fun getTopicListLiveData():LiveData<List<FilteringTopicEntity>>
```

**LiveData - Listening Changes:**

```html
viewModel.getTopicListLiveData().observe(this, { list: List<FilteringTopicEntity> ->
            itemAdapter?.let {
                it.setData(list.toMutableList())
            }.orElse {
                itemAdapter = TopicListingAdapter(list
                    .toMutableList(), itemListener)
                itemTopicRecyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Item Received ${list.size}")
        })
```

**Inserting into DB**

```kotlin
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract fun updateFilterTopic(copyDataEntity: FilteringTopicEntity)
```

**Updating DB Row value**

```kotlin
    override fun updateTopic(topicEntity: FilteringTopicEntity) {
        topicEntity.updatedAt = DateTime()
        topicListDao.updateFilterTopic(topicEntity)
    }
```

```kotlin
class MediaDiffCallback(
        private val oldList: MutableList<FilteringTopicEntity>,
        private val newList: MutableList<FilteringTopicEntity>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldList.size

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newList.size

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition].id == newList[newItemPosition].id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldPosition: Int, newPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldPosition].updatedAt ==  newList[newPosition].updatedAt
        }

        @Nullable
        override fun getChangePayload(oldPosition: Int, newPosition: Int): Any? {
            return super.getChangePayload(oldPosition, newPosition)
        }
    }
```

Adapter complete code : [link](https://gist.github.com/merlinJeyakumar/097f81198445e8474e66caad22efa424)

**I tried several solutions** nothing works for that issue

- I tried `toMutableList()` & `toList()`
- I tried data class and converting it into `objectList.map {it.copy}.toList()`
- Extracting values and adding to another object instance and new list
- Tried to update latest livedata, room dependencies

> LiveData received items present already in the adapter without set

**Please help to find out notifying list item changes without `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to integrate things properly with `DiffUtils`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Initially, list items loaded within the adapter and **selected item** changed and replaced to DB.

```kotlin
    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun updateFilterTopic(copyDataEntity: FilteringTopicEntity)
```

Here, the problem is I used the same item instance which room DB returned before.

> So. I reassigned values to the new instance and updated it to DB, now updates receiving as expected.

```kotlin
open class FilteringTopicEntity() : com.support.room.BaseEntity(), Parcelable {
    fun copy(filteringTopicEntity: FilteringTopicEntity): FilteringTopicEntity {
        filteringTopicEntity.id = id
        filteringTopicEntity.updatedAt = updatedAt
        filteringTopicEntity.createdAt = createdAt
        return filteringTopicEntity
    }
}
```

**Here I showed, how I copied a value**

```kotlin
    filteringTopicEntity.copy(FilteringTopicEntity()
```

Comment: Hey @MerlinJeyakumar can you please look at my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70095578/11560810)